# JavaScript: Understanding closures and hoisting

Tags: javascript, closures, hoisting

I understand that function declarations are hoisted to the top of their scope. This allows us to use those functions before they're actually declared in JavaScript:

```
sayHello(); // It works!

function sayHello() {
  console.log('Hello');
}
```

I also understand that closures enable functions to retain references to variables declared within the same scope:

```
function outerFxn() {
  let num = 0;

  function innerFxn() {
    console.log(num);
    num++;
  }

  return innerFxn;
}

const logNum = outerFxn();
logNum(); // 0
logNum(); // 1
logNum(); // 2
```

So far so good. But here's some weirdness that I'm hoping someone can explain exactly what's going on...

### Scenario 1: understandable closure

```
function zero(cb) {
  return setTimeout(cb, 0);
}

function test1() {
  let txt = 'this is a test message';

  function log() {
    console.log(txt);
  }

  zero(log);
}
```

In the example above, the `log` function retains a reference to the scope in which it was created, holding on the the `txt` variable. Then, when executed later on in the `setTimeout`, it successfully log's the `txt` variable's value. Great. Then there's this...

### Scenario 2: what is happening?

```
function zero(cb) {
  return setTimeout(cb, 0);
}

function test1() {
  function log() {
    console.log(txt);
  }

  let txt = 'this is a test message';

  zero(log);
}
```

I've moved the `log` function declaration to the top of the scope (it would have been hoisted there anyway, right?), *then* I'm declaring the `txt` variable below it. This all still works and I'm not sure why. How is `log` retaining a reference to the `txt` variable when `let`'s and `const`'s aren't hoisted up? Are closure scopes analyzed *as-a-whole*? I could use a bit of clarity on what the JavaScript engine is doing step by step here. Thank you SO land!

Comment: you could simply use this alternative snippet: function f() { console.log("a1: " + a); a = 123; console.log("a2: " + a) } both the log print 123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Are closure scopes analyzed as-a-whole?" - yes. Closures retain the scope as it is at the moment you (lexically) leave it. In your example, `txt` does exist when you reach the closing `}` in `test1`, so it's in the scope, and `log` has no problems accessing it.

Note "lexically" above: bindings are done prior to runtime, when only thing that matters is your block structure. So even this would work, although it shouldn't from the "dynamic" point of view:

```
function test1() {
    function log() {
        console.log(txt);
    }

    zero(log);
    let txt = 'this is a test message';
}
```

Comment: I had a hunch that scope is analyzed as a whole. "... the moment you lexically leave it" - _that_ was what I didn't understand. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

It's part of the scope after you leave the `test1` function. It doesn't matter if it's being used with `var`, `let` or `const` at that point. Since the whole body has been evaluated, the variable exists on the scope.

Had you tried to use `log` before the `let` declaration is evaluated, you'd gotten an error.

**Edit**: Technically, the variables declared with `let` and `const` are in scope, but they are unitialized which results in an error if you try to access them. It's only until you get to the declarations that they are initialized and you can access them. So they are always in scope, just not available until declarations are evaluated.

Comment: Your edit looks wrong to me. It's `var`s that are hoisted (exist but not initialized), `let`s do not physically exist before declaration.

Comment: @georg, they do exist before declaration. Otherwise they could be superseded on higher scopes, but they don't. They are references that are not initialized yet, but they do exist.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Like `{ let p = 1; { p++; let p = 2 } }`, right? So they kind of bear a "do not use" marker before declaration. Good point!

Answer (score 0):

In **Scenario 2** you are doing:

1. `let txt = 'this is a test message'` which means that `txt` will be part of the scope of `test1()`.
2. At the same time you are declaring `log()` which will have access to
   the scope of its parent `test1()`.

So what happens on run-time? `test1()` will be evaluated and as such `log()` will have access to the scope of `test1()`. This means that `txt` will be available for `log()` to use immediately.

Tip: debug it, put some break points and see what happens.

**Edit:** You can also consider that within `log()`, `txt` is not defined and as such its value should be undefined... right? The fact that `console.log(txt)` works outputs `this is a test message` is due to the above explanation on scoping. It's always good practice to declare your variables at the top of the function scope, and your functions at the bottom of the scope since they will be evaluated first anyways. Consider the human factor in this situation, best practice can also mean: for you/anyone to understand what the code does just by reading it.

Answer (score 0):

this is a timing/execution order thing. Think about it like

```
function test1(){
    var context = { }; 

    function log(){
        if(context.hasOwnProperty("txt")){
            console.log(context.txt); 
        }else{
            throw new Error("there is no value 'txt' declared in this context");
        }
    }

    context.txt = 'this is a test message';
    log();
}
```

Same in your code with the not hoisted variable `txt`. At the time, `log` is executed, `let txt` will have been declared in the proper function context. It is available even if it ain't hoisted. The function `log` doesn't store a reference to the variable itself, but to the whole surrounding execution context, and this context stores the variables.